# React best practice for Redux and local state

Tags: reactjs, redux, architecture

I am building an Instagram like web-app and on the feed page, I am displaying the posts of the users.
The posts are fetched by dispatching a redux action.
Now, the posts can have media and I have to fetch them singularly, so it does not make sense to me to store that in the redux store, cause they just need to be available to the single post and to no one else. So basically my code structure is as follow:

```
PostCard.js

const PostCard = ({ post }) => {

    const [loadingMedia, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [medias, setMedias] = useState([]);

    const { age_of_post_in_seconds, created_by, has_media, uuid, text, like_count_total, comments_total, liked_by_me, bookmarked_by_me } = post;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (has_media) fetchMedia();
        else setLoading(false);
    }, [])

    async function fetchMedia() {
        setLoading(true);
        const medias = await getPostMedia(uuid);
        if (!medias) console.log('there was an error')
        else setMedias(medias);
        setLoading(false);
    }

{.....more irrelevant code.....}

    return (
        <Body>
            <Card>
                <Header caption={text} name={created_by.handle} time={age_of_post_in_seconds} uniqueName={created_by.display_name} avatar={created_by.profile_photo} />
                {has_media && !loadingMedia && <Media medias={medias} />}
                <Footer
                    likes={like_count_total}
                    liked={liked_by_me}
                    bookmarked={bookmarked_by_me}
                    id={uuid}
                    likePost={handleLikePost}
                    bookmarkPost={handleBookmarkPost}
                    showComments={handleShowComments}
                    comments_total={comments_total}
                />
                {visibleComments && <Comment comments={comments} />}
                {<AddComment postId={uuid} sendComment={handleCommentPost} />}
            </Card>
        </Body>
    )
}

export default PostCard;
```

and I store my actions **both redux actions and just plain actions** in this file

```
{----some code---}

export const fetchPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCHING_FEED_POSTS })
    await vueApi.get('/posts')
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_FEED_POSTS_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
            history.push('/home')
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('fetch posts failed with error', e)
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_FEED_POSTS_FAILED, payload: e })
        })
}


export const getPostMedia = async (id) => {
    let error = false;
    const response = await vueApi.get(`/posts/${id}/media`)
        .catch((e) => error = true);
    if (!error) return response.data
    else return false
}
```

Now my question is: Is it bad practice to 1) use a mix of redux and local state in this case 2) use a mix of redux actions and "plain" actions in the same action.js file?

Comment: A common problem is that people "overuse" Redux state. I often use a mix of Redux and local state. Redux makes sense for "global" state, i.e. data that is consumed by multiple "unrelated" components. Local state is good for date that only the current component cares about, i.e. data that will only be used by the current component and potentially passed as props to children.

Comment: Thanks Carlton, i completely agree. What is your opinion about having both helper functions and redux actions in the same file ?

Comment: I like to keep them separate. I'll use separate files for redux actions, reducers and selectors. If my app is large I'll even create a folder per reducer (i.e. "Settings", "TodoItems", etc) then a file for the reducer, action and selectors inside.